# How to access SVN repository on another computer using Windows Credentials from Jenkins

Tags: windows, svn, jenkins

We are on a LAN. One of our computers has Jenkins installed. On another computer in the same LAN is our SVN repository. The repository is only accesible after we login to the server using username and password.

How can we setup our computer so Jenkins can login to the server and see when our SVN repository receives new commits etc?

Answer (score 0):

Install Jenkins SVN plugin (Hpi file format) from jenkins site and after installing Jenkins svn plugin, you have to restart the Jenkins. You will find the check box for every successive changes or commit, it will start building the application.

Comment: My problem is that the repository is behind a windows authentication login.

Comment: You need to get the commercial version of Jenkins preferably from cloudbees, open source version of Jenkins don't have this option.  Also, you can configure the authentication and authorization to your project team to monitor the svn commits/changes in Enterprise Jenkins (Enterprise Edition from cloudbees).